# Is the Minkowski metric coordinate independent?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, covariance

Suppose I have some vector $\mathbf{P} = p^{\mu} e_{\mu}$.

Now, for a flat spacetime, the contravariant components can be lowered via the Minkowski metric,

$$ p_{\mu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} p^{\nu}.$$

My question is, does $\eta_{\mu \nu} = (-1,1,1,1)$ always, for all coordinates? My immediate response would be **no**, only for Cartesian coordinates, as in the [Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor_(general_relativity)#Flat_spacetime). However, the motivation for this question is from my inability to understand the step in going from eqn B5 to B6 in [Kulkarni et al. 2011](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0010).

In this paper the author appears to be working in spherical polar coordinates, but makes a transform using the Cartesian metric. Surely instead the metric in spherical coordinates should be used?

Comment: Such "Am I right?" questions are difficult to answer. What except "Yes, you're right" do you expect an answerer to write here in the case where you are right?

Comment: Well, really I expect to be *wrong*; that there is somewhere a hole in my understanding and that I am not understanding the linked paper correctly. I then expect an answer to point out this hole?

Comment: So you expect answerers to read the linked paper? It would help if you cited the relevant section directly, then.

Comment: In the paper you refer to, they use a formulation of general relativity called the Tetrad Formalism. Here the metric is always $(-1,1,1,1)$ and information about the curvature of the spacetime is encoded in the basis vectors at each point of the tangent space (which by construction are always orthonormal to one another).

Comment: @Greg.Paul I lilke your comment but since precision of ideas is crucial here, I think you should not say "at each point of the tangent space" but rather "at each point of the manifold" (because there is not one tangent space but many)

Comment: @Greg.Paul: How about converting that comment into an answer? (And maybe you could also explicitly tell the OP that yes, the components of the metric are normally coordinate-dependent, and address Andrew Steane's comment, which I think is correct.)

Comment: @Greg.Paul Ok interesting. So in the comoving tetrad frame, the basis vectors are just orthonormal Cartesian basis vectors?